# I can't intercept a rest web service with spring aop pointcut

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, aspectj, spring-aop

I use spring aop to intercept a Get web service call, to do that, this is my code:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class RestInterceptor {
    @Around("@annotation(javax.ws.rs.GET)")
    public Object authorizeGetMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        Object value = null;
        try {
            value = pjp.proceed();
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

When I call a Get web service the code above is never called (the web service work correctly) but the same code works when I change the annotation by `@annotation(org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional)`

---

**Update (edit by @kriegaex, copied from comment):**

@Nikolas the code in the interface is

```java
@GET
Response getAll(
    @QueryParam("q") String filter,
    @QueryParam("field") List<String> fields
);
```

and the implementation

```java
@Override public Response getAll(String filter, List<String> fields) {
    return Response.ok(
        // this.getConverter(this.getService().findAll(filter), fields)
    ).build();
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the method with `@GET` implementation and it's class header with all the annotations used.

Comment: Do try this `@Around("@annotation(get)") public Object authorizeGetMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, GET get) { ... }` and share result

Comment: @Bond-JavaBond i did a test and i had the same behavior; the method inside the aspect class are not called and the web service respond correctly.

Comment: @Nikolas the code in the interface `@GET
    Response getAll(@QueryParam("q") String filter, @QueryParam("field") List<String> fields);`and the implementation `@Override
    public Response getAll(String filter, List<String> fields) {
        
        return Response.ok( //
                        this.getConverter(this.getService().findAll(filter), fields))
                .build();
    }`

Comment: Try it without using interfaces.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha i think understand what's happen, with spring aop you can't make a pointcut out of a bean in my case the interface are out of the spring context unlike to the implementation class with '@service' so i decide to make a new annotation and use it in the implementation side, may be my case can help others :)

Comment: @yobs, comments are not the right place for sample code, please edit your question instead next time, I just did that for you. Please check if I did it right and fix it if I got it wrong. Without line feeds in the comment it was hard to tell. As for your last comment, it does not matter if the annotation is from Spring or not. Only the code you want to intercept needs to be inside a Spring bean/component. As you did not provide that code (which you should always do with AOP questions because an aspect alone does not tell others why it is not working), I cannot know.

Comment: _(continued)_ If you want to intercept non-Spring code from within a Spring application, you still have the option of using full AspectJ. The Spring manual describes how to use [AspectJ via load-time weaving (LTW)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) in detail.